# Ajax begin form unobstrusive.js not working in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

We are using Ajax Begin form in one of our page for post action. This is working fine normally. But when I am on Experience Editor unobstrucive.js is not working properly and the result is loaded in new window. How do I get this working?

Comment: why are you testing post functionality in experience editor?

Comment: Business is asking for..

Comment: @VisvaKiruthikaMuthuraj you can try to use Preview mode instead of Editing in Experience Editor (EE). But usually, EE scripts might conflict with 3d party libraries, so this is a well-known issue.

Comment: This was working earlier in experience editor. Not sure why it stopped working @Alexander

Comment: @VisvaKiruthikaMuthuraj we don't have access to your repo, that's why we cannot help you, but you can try to revert your commits to the stable state and then check the difference of the commit between current and stable states, it should help to find the problem.

Comment: @VisvaKiruthikaMuthuraj you can also compare Sitecore instances if you have a stable version using compare/merge tools.

Comment: @Alexander Seems like the issue is due to the script place holder we have added in the layout for Experience Editor. Without this we are not getting the Experience Editor ribbon. Once I removed the script placeholder, ajax function is working. But the issue I am facing now is I am not getting Context on Ajax function call.  Due to which I am getting Context.Pagemode.IsExperienceEditor as false.  And page redirection happens which is causing CORS error.